# Autojump auto-complete feature does not work

Tags: bash, autocomplete, autojump

On my configuration, autojump *autocomplete* feature does not seem to work. To be clear, autojump works properly, only the autocomplete feature fails to work.

When I press the `<TAB>` key, the autocompletion menu is not displayed but the directory name I typed is partially enclosed in quotes.

Here is what happens. **Note that after typing liba, I pressed the `<TAB>` key multiple times**. I would have expected autojump to cycle through `/tmp/liba1` and `/tmp/liba2`. Also not that `/tmp/liba2` only appears after I pressed the`<ENTER>` key.

[image: Autojump autocompletion attempt]

I am using :

- Konsole 2.12.4 (KDE 4.12.4) (but I have the same issue with xterm)
- Liquidprompt
- Bash 4.3.11
- Autojump 21.6.9

Here is the bottom of my `.bashrc` file :

```
# Alias definitions.
# You may want to put all your additions into a separate file like
# ~/.bash_aliases, instead of adding them here directly.
# See /usr/share/doc/bash-doc/examples in the bash-doc package.

if [ -f ~/.bash_aliases ]; then
    . ~/.bash_aliases
fi

# enable programmable completion features (you don't need to enable
# this, if it's already enabled in /etc/bash.bashrc and /etc/profile
# sources /etc/bash.bashrc).
if ! shopt -oq posix; then
  if [ -f /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion ]; then
    . /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion
  elif [ -f /etc/bash_completion ]; then
    . /etc/bash_completion
  fi
fi

# Liquidprompt
source ~/.liquidprompt/liquidprompt
# Autojump
. /usr/share/autojump/autojump.bash
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apparently this is an autojump bug : [Bad bash tab completion #228](https://github.com/joelthelion/autojump). Manually installing the latest version of autojump solves the issue.

```
git clone git://github.com/joelthelion/autojump.git
cd autojump
./install.py
vim ~/.bashrc
# Add line [[ -s /home/fabien/.autojump/etc/profile.d/autojump.sh ]] && 
# source /home/fabien/.autojump/etc/profile.d/autojump.sh
```